Unable to edit list in Field Map Designer after import from ArcGIS Pro
I created the layer in ArcGIS Pro, which was the next style. The style is based upon categorization, therefore I had to create the new field in ArcGIS Pro, which I normally used to do in Field Maps Designer.
Next, I've read about domains, that they should be assigned for our new field.
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geodatabases/overview/create-modify-and-delete-domains.htm

Unfortunately, the Field Maps Designer doesn't recognize this field at all. It's just visible, but there is no option for adding & modifying the list.

I found a similar problem here:
Unable to create domain for feature layer using ArcGIS Field Maps
although without a solution.
I am asking what causes the problem. From my understanding, the field created in ArcGIS Pro should be editable later in Field Maps Designer.
What is the reason hindering it from further alterations? This approach would save me a lot of time, as I could prepare style (lyrx) files based on categorized styles necessary for further work. So far I used to do everything manually in Field Maps Designer.
Is there any solution for it?

Have you tried creating another duplicate field and domain? @Geographos

No, I haven't duplicated anything

I would say best practise is:

Prepare geodatabase feature class in ArcGIS Pro
Create domains
Assign domains in ArcGIS Pro and test to ensure its working as expected
Share as web layer and turn on sync so it can be used in field maps.

This sequence has always worked for me. I would not be creating lists in ArcGIS Online (AGOL) after I have uploaded a layer.

The worst thing is - how to assign a domain correctly. I've assigned a few of them and none of them was working honestly.

Even if domain is successfully created, the list still cannot be edited
